# How to send request from server side with NextJS/ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, api, security, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm looking for a solution to request my (Spring boot) API from my NextJS/React front but server side so that I'm not showing my endpoints in the network browser. I was able to use "getServerSideProps" (from NextJS) for GET request because it is happening before rendering. Now I'm looking for a solution of sending a POST request for exemple an authentication. Any ideas ?

I was thinking I could send the requests from "getServerSideProps", then come back to my form I just submit if the answer was an error but it doesn't look like a good practice to me, am I right ?